# DocuSign: How to check the reminder status for an envelope

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a way to know if reminders are sent for an envelope in DocuSign?
I logged in as admin and could find any option to see the reminder status.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the way to see the reminder status is behind the getEnvelopeInformation API, this returns the following information, however it does not tell you how much time is left until it expires.

```
  "expireEnabled": "true",
  "expireDateTime": "2020-12-11T22:01:21.1300000Z",
  "expireAfter": "114",
```

For more information I share the following link: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/get-envelope-information/

Regards,

Eric